# Should I add 'the' in titles?

Tags: articles

I am recently writing a proposal titled "Evaluating and Optimizing (the) Utility of Explanations". But I am not sure if I should include 'the' before 'Utility' in the title. Actually this question has always been bothering me. Is there any difference in the use of 'the' in titles v.s. bodies?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't really that much of a difference in the use of grammar in titles vs bodies. Grammar should be used correctly in both circumstances. One way of trying to figure out which one to use is by putting the title into a sentence. E.g. Would you say 'I am evaluating and optimising utility of explanations.' in a real life situation? Of course the answer is no. Hence, my answer to your question is 'yes, you do add the 'the''. Obviously with titles, you will capitalise all words apart from the prepositions, articles and conjunctions.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: When you use "Evaluating and Optimizing the Utility of Explanations", the use of 'the' may trigger a question ' which utility...?' because it shows a little bit of specificity here.  Without  'the' that is "Evaluating and Optimizing Utility of Explanations", utility of explanations is a generation thing without any specificity to which the reader is drawn.  Thus, it is the choice of the writer what he needs.

Comment: There's normally a bit more looseness with grammar in titles, as in other cases where you're not writing continuous formal prose: the same rule applies to signs, headlines, labels, product names, songs, band names, etc. It's particularly common to drop articles.